# How to return rows containing decimals in a range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have the following table:

| Rows | Decimals |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1.1.1.3.2 |
| Second | 16.1.1.1.89.1 |
| Third | 3.1.1.1.177.2 |
| Fourth | 1.1.1.1.178.3 |

I only want to return the rows where the second to last decimal is between 0.7 to 0.94 (inclusive), but all the other numbers can contain any value. For the above table, this would be only the second row. How can I specify my query to specifically look at the second to last decimal place?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT Rows FROM table
WHERE Decimals like %.%.%.7.% < %.%.%.94.%;
```

Comment: What code have you written so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Did you you use a regex to pick out the 2nd-to-last element? Did you put it in a new column? In a CTE? In a temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select `rows`,
       `decimals`
  from your_table
 where substring_index(reverse(substring_index(reverse(`decimals`),'.',2)),'.',1) between 7 and 94;
```